# Expo/React Native: Can't find image file after ejecting to bare workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo project with an `<Image />` component sourced from an import:

```
import logoImage from './assets/logo-medium.png';

...

<Image source={logoImage} />
```

This works fine on my device when building with `expo run:ios -d`. However, when I build the project with XCode, the image isn't there, and I see this error:

```
[native] Could not find image file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B76D59AF-9599-4174-991B-AE484575B79C/data/Containers/Data/Application/A57C6E10-3DF9-46E0-8B56-7760AF5199C6/Library/Application%20Support/.expo-internal/assets/assets/logo-medium.png
```

When I try to find that file manually, there is no `...Application Support/.expo-internal` directory.

Is there a different way I should be specifying image location? Or a way for the image to be correctly bundled when building from XCode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, make sure about two things:

1. One of the potential solutions found on the web -
   https://forums.expo.dev/t/assets-missing-only-in-ios-release-build-after-ejecting/42759

> ```
> Ok I found out the problem.
> When ejecting, expo is supposed to generate a metro.config.js file that looks like that:
>
> module.exports = {
>   transformer: {
>       assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles']
>   }
> };
> ```

2. Your `metro.config.js` file shuld has `.js` extensions not `.ts`

Comment: A million thanks, this appears to have worked! I now have my image back.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, my production build keeps being blank when upgrading from SDK 41 to 47, this really solved my issue!