# native Could not find image './expo-asset/assets/${your_img_path}' not found in React Native / Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

As my project is expo ejected react native project and I'm getting the error [native] Could not find image on path

**'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/..../Library/Application%20Support/.expo-internal/assets/...'**

`"react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.0", "expo": "~41.0.1", "expo-error-recovery": "^2.1.0", "expo-font": "~9.1.0", "expo-modules-core": "^0.2.0", "expo-splash-screen": "^0.10.3", "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4", "expo-updates": "^0.5.5",`

I have tried this solutions but not working any solution for my code

[Firebase Cloud Messaging - Handling logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193215/firebase-cloud-messaging-handling-logout)

[Expo/React Native: Can't find image file after ejecting to bare workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968225/expo-react-native-cant-find-image-file-after-ejecting-to-bare-workflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case after ejecting from expo I haven't changed this **AppDelegate.m** file

[AppDelegate.M file line no 52 - 58](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXtCE.jpg)

[AppDelegate.M file line no 92 - 98](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc0lz.jpg)

please, make these changes in project/ios/your_project_name/AppDelegate.m
make sure to change line number 52 to 58 according to image 1.
make sure to change line number 92 to 98 according to image 2.

This works fine for me. Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks Man ! @Ankit . I was trying from past 2 days but no luck. This saved my time !!

Answer (score 2):

Check this

**1)** When ejecting, expo is supposed to generate a metro.config.js file that looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
      assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles']
  }
};
```

**2)** Your metro.config.js file should have **.js** extensions not .ts

Comment: Hi I have tried this solution but still i'm not getting the images in release ios build while in debug ios build it is woring fine

Comment: Try @Ankit solution, it is working for me...