# Blank white screen when expo app uploaded to TestFlight (built with EAS)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, testflight

My React native app is bundled using EAS.

When I run my app using `expo start` or `expo start --no-dev --minify` on expo go or the xcode simulator via expo, I get no issues and my app runs flawlessly. When I compile the app with EAS, use Apple's Transporter to upload it to AppConnect and then put it on testflight, I just get a blank white screen whenever I open the app (after first install and after closing it and reopening). I have no idea whether it is something wrong with my env set up or the dependancies I'm using or my actual app code.
Please Help!

This is my app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "NAME",
    "slug": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/applogo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/icon.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "identifier",
      "buildNumber": "4"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": ""
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "homepage": "",
  "author": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli": "^10.7.1",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^5.0.14",
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.267.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.1.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.0.14",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "expo": "^48.0.19",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1293.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-loader-pulse": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Result of `npx expo-env-info`

```
 expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 13.4
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 8.5.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
      Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^48.0.19 => 48.0.19 
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-native: 0.71.8 => 0.71.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 3.13.3
      expo-cli: 6.3.8
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue while upgrading a project from SDK 41 to 47. The iOS version looked fine in the Expo Go app, but after building it using EAS, the app became completely blank.

From the device log, it seems the static image is missing in the bundle.

The root cause of the problem in my case was the `metro.config.js` file.

> When ejecting, expo is supposed to generate a `metro.config.js` file that looks like that
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>    transformer: {
>        assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles']
>    }
> };
> ```

However, in our project, we had previously created this file to support `svg` assets requested by `react-native-svg-transformer`, so Expo didn't overwrite it since it already existed.

The solution was to merge the Expo-generated configuration into our existing `metro.config.js` file. After doing this, the production build finally displayed its contents correctly.

Here's the updated `metro.config.js`:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config")

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname)

  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
      assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles']
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  }
})()
```

I want to give credit to [r1skz3ro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70245884/8581245) and this [Expo forum thread](https://forums.expo.dev/t/assets-missing-only-in-ios-release-build-after-ejecting/42759) for helping me find this solution. Huge thanks.

---

Here are some debugging tips that I found helpful:

1. To make the debug process faster, I have run the production build locally for easier testing. The step is like this:

- run `npx expo prebuild` to generate the `ios` folder,
- open the `.xcworkspace` file and build the app using the XCode IDE
- Alternatively, you can run `npx expo start --ios --no-dev` to build the application.

  Although the actual build time is similar to EAS build, this approach reduces the time to download the build and the processing time when uploading to Testflight.

2. View the crash log on a real device or on the simulator. (I will try writing the steps later when I got time)